# downloadURL function returns nil (Swift 5)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to retrieve multiple pictures I uploaded to Firebase Storage by downloading each image's url and store them into my database. Whenever I need it, I will be able to load the image just by loading the url.

What I am doing is download the url at the same time when I am uploading them. The problem is when there is only one picture, it works fine but when I upload 2 or more, the downloadURL function(imgURL) keeps returning nil. The pictures are all correctly uploaded into the storage which means the putData() function works fine each time. Then I am wondering why is this happening? Thanks

```
for i in 0..<imageData.count {
            let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
            let imgRef = storageRef.child("Posts Pictures/\(userID)/\(postID)/\(imageName).jpg")

            imgRef.putData(imageData[i], metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    completion(false, "")
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }

                imgRef.downloadURL(completion: {(imgURL, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        // This is where it crashes
                        print(error!)
                        completion(false, "")
                        return
                    }

                    let url = ["imageURL\(i)": imgURL?.absoluteString]
                    postImages.updateChildValues(url as [AnyHashable : Any], withCompletionBlock: {(err, ref) in
                        if err != nil {
                            print(err!)
                            completion(false, "")
                            return
                        }
                        completion(true, "")
                    })
                })
            })
            })
        }
```

Comment: The issue it is probably the fact that you are using the same imgRef object for all uploads/downloads. Try a single one and see if the problem persists

Comment: That is a local variable @Leo Dabus

Comment: you are calling an asynchronous method. You need to keep a reference to your imgRef objects

Comment: You mean declare the variable outside the loop?

Comment: Try creating an array for your image references